# Who is responsible of decoding request parameters?

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I developed REST server, using Jersey and Embedded-Tomcat.

When my client, using Jersey, send a request to my server and add request parameter which it's value is UTF-8 encoded, I receive the parameter decoded in the server side.

My question is, who is responsible of decoding this parameter? Is it tomcat? Jersey?
Can I disable this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server container is responsible for decoding the request parameters. You can't disable it